# Select post from two tag (AND)

Tags: mysql, sql

tag

```
tag_id      tag          post_id 
--------------------------------
1           category1    1
2           category2    1
3           etc          2
4           category3    1
```

post

```
post_id title
-------------
1       title1
```

How can we get `title1` because its in the tag `category1` && `category2`

something like

```
SELECT TITLE 
  FROM post, tag 
 WHERE tag.post_id = post.post_id 
   AND tags.tag = 'category1','category2'
```

Comment: What about post_id=1 instead of comparing with categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check if a title has BOTH 'category1' and 'category2', you can use the following SQL query:

```
SELECT title 
FROM post 
JOIN tag ON post.post_id = tag.post_id 
WHERE tag.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag = 'category1')
AND tag.tag = 'category2';
```

To check for other categories you just repeat the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT title 
FROM post 
JOIN tag ON post.post_id = tag.post_id 
WHERE tag.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag = 'category1')
AND tag.tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tag WHERE tag = 'category2')
AND tag.tag = 'category3';
```

This would return results for titles that have all 3 categories.

Comment: You are correct. I've modified the query so that it will require both categories. You can accomplish this by using a nested SELECT statement. In this case it's getting all IDs that have 'category1' as a tag, and then it's looking to see which of those also have 'category2' as a tag.

Comment: how about more then two? how would you do it?

Comment: Depends on the combo, you can just add additional 'where' statements by connecting them with 'AND' (see above). I'll update the query to show you.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both tables like this:

```
SELECT post.* 
FROM post 
LEFT JOIN tag
ON post.post_id = tag.post_id
WHERE tag.tag IN ('category1','category2')
GROUP BY post.post_id
HAVING COUNT(post.post_id) >1;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/556347/9)

Note: If we don't use `HAVING` clause, It will also return records where any single value exists

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14da1/2)

[See the similar requirement with similar table structure.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13319935/1369235)