# select relevance title based on tag similar to like with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, search, relevance

TAGS

```
tag_id   post_id   value
------------------------
1        1         some
2        1         good
3        1         title
4        2         some
5        2         good
6        3         some
7        4         good
8        4         title
```

POSTS

```
post_id  title
-------------------
1        some good title
2        some good
3        some
4        good title
```

how can we get the post_id = 1 and 2 that contains value **`some` and `good`** in the same post_id?

so the result is

```
RESULT
title
----------
some good title
some good
```

`good title` dosent show becouse there is no `some` value in post_id = 4 in tags.
`some` doesnt show beouse the requirement `good`

Comment: It [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13319538/1369235) your account?

Comment: nope, btw its quite similar. thats for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `LIKE` multiple time:

```
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE title LIKE '%some%'
AND title LIKE '%good%'
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a37/1)

You can also join both tables like this:

```
SELECT post.post_id, title FROM Post
RIGHT JOIN Tags
ON post.post_id = tags.post_id
WHERE Tags.value IN ('some','good')
GROUP BY post.Post_ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a37/9)

Note: If we don't use `HAVING` clause, It will also return records where any single value exists

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a37/11)

[See the similar requirement with similar table structure.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13319538/1369235)

Comment: how about the performance? can we utilize the tags? or we better don't need to do that?

Comment: thanks hims, can you explain about having count(*)>1 what does that do?

Comment: If we don't use `HAVING`, it will also give us records which contains any one value (e.g. some,good) [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a37/10) without `HAVING`